# Creating custom length password in Rijndael Cryptography Algorithm

Tags: c#, rijndael

I'm using c# for implementing Rijndael algorithm to encrypt/decrypt files. Below is my code:

```
private void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile, string password)
        {

            try
            {

                UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
                byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password.ToString());

                string cryptFile = outputFile;
                FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

                RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                    RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                    CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

                int data;
                while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    cs.WriteByte((byte)data);


                fsIn.Close();
                cs.Close();
                fsCrypt.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Now, the thing is that, the function works only if password length is a multiple of 8. that is, if the password length is 8,16,32, etc., then it works else not.

Comment: Using the key for the IV defeats the purpose of CBC and substantially reduces security.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  You need to learn far more about cryptography before you can safely use cryptographic primitives.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question :)

Comment: @SLaks, I agree with both your comments but, this is a good place to do some learning.

Comment: @Jodrell: No; this is much too broad to be taught on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Simply taking the password and getting its Unicode representation in bytes makes pretty terrible key. Please don't do that! The correct way to go is to use a salted hash as a key -- that is, take a salt, a password, and mix them together with a hash function.

To derive a key from a variable-length password, use PBKDF2. PBKDF2 is designed to make brute forcing slower when the attacker has fast access to the data.

```
string password = ...;
byte[] salt = ...;
int keyLength = 32;

byte[] key;

using(var pbkdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt))
{
    key = pbkdf.GetBytes(keyLength);
}
```

If you need something which uses less CPU, HMAC will work but also be faster to brute force:

```
using(var hmac = new HMACSHA256())
{
    hmac.Key = salt;
    key = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
}
```

Note that there exists hardware now which can very effectively attack PBKDF2 so this won't do much to help against a determined attacker with resources. If this is important to you, branching out of the .NET base classes and using a more modern algorithm like [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) might be preferred.

Comment: Indeed. Trying to keep the answer more specific to his inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code =>

```
 string passwordFlagLength(string password)
 {
    int count = 1
    for (int i = 0 to 31)
    {

        if (password.length == count) return password;
        if (password.length < count) return password + new string("x", count - password.length);
        count = count * 2
    }
 }
```

This takes a password and makes it length 1, 2, 4, 8, etc...   up to a 31 bit value.(int w/out negative)

if the value is already a proper flag size number, it uses it, otherwise it fills in the rest with "x"

--> Note: I agree with everyone elses comments regarding better was to do security/issues, I just posted this, because the immediate issue posted was due to a string size not being a base 2 bit value.  I also just applied the count which I forgot in my original code